# Use the Wikipedia hyperlink symbol in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, wikipedia

I have some hyperlinks in my Word document and I wish to add the Wikipedia symbol for the Hyperlink: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:External_link_icons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aExternal_link_icons)
( the one with the Square and the arrow ).

I think it would really improve the appearance. If not, is there some alternative symbol ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste (or insert) whatever image into a word document. If your source image is in a browser, right click the image and select "Copy image", go to Word and paste it. If your source image is in a file on your local drive or a network drive, use e.g. Word's Insert / Picture function. Position the image in Word in the usual way, then right-click the image and select "Edit hyperlink ..." from the context menu. In the address field (center bottom) you add the URL.